# How can I host SVG images on my website using firebase?

Tags: html, image, firebase, web, firebase-hosting

I have deployed a site to Firebase hosting and everything works great, expect that the images are not loading.

I'm linking to them in the public folder that I deploy to the host.

Do I need to add them to something like FireStore and link to that URL?

```
<img class="img-fluid img" src="/Users/myprofile/desktop/folder/public/name.svg" alt="">
```

(I have removed the original path)

The alt is empty.

Thank you

Comment: Don't use local file paths in your web content.  That won't work when deployed.  Use URIs that refer to other deployed content.  All of your content should be in the public folder and be reference by relative URIs.

Comment: @DougStevenson They were not in the public folder, but I have now moved them to it and changed the path. They are still not deployed.
I can see from firebase that the website has been updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was linking with the full url.
Like so:
`src="/Users/myprofile/desktop/folder/public/name.svg"`

As the pictures was in the same public folder, I only need to use the `name.svg`.